# Does each request access the same servlet object?

Tags: java, http, servlets, request

Does each HTTP request access the same servlet object but in a different thread? or does it create a new thread and new  Servlet Instance ?

Comment: Why not to instantiate a servlet upon request?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do servlets work? Instantiation, session variables and multithreading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-session-variables-and-multithreading)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The container will use the same servlet instance if your servlet don't implement `SingleThreadModel`.
Otherwise there is no guarantee that the same `Servlet` object is hit. The container is free to create more servlet instances if it considers necessary. But the requests comes on different threads, not necessarily newly created (as Sanjay mentioned).

From the Servlet 3.0 specification:

> For a servlet not hosted in a distributed environment (the default), the servlet
>   container must use only one instance per servlet declaration. However, for a servlet
>   implementing the SingleThreadModel interface, the servlet container may
>   instantiate multiple instances to handle a heavy request load and serialize requests
>   to a particular instance.

...

> Generally the Web container handles concurrent requests to the same servlet by
>   concurrent execution of the service method on different threads.

Answer (score 9):

Each HTTP request creates a new thread but accesses the same instance of the Servlet.

EDIT: In case of one server node, you will have the same Servlet instance on that node. In case of load balancing/many servers you will usually have one instance per Java VM.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't really *create* a new thread always; more like picks up a free thread from an existing thread pool.

Comment: @SanjayT.Sharma You are right, it's often done this way (for performance reasons), but this is implementation detail of application server/servlet container and your code should not depend on that