# How does a single servlet handle multiple requests from client side

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets

How does a single servlet handle multiple client requests coming in the form of user requests ? Based on the singleton design pattern I know we get a single instance of servlet created , but how does a single servlet handle millions of requests . Confused about the threading involved in it also.

Also does any browser specifications or settings come handy out here for sending the requests across or generating the threads sent out for the requests.

Is it the same for all frameworks or it differs say for example struts v/s springs ?

Comment: The servlets are pooled, there isn't just a single instance at a time.

Comment: You might wanna take a look at [connector pools](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23507_01/Platform.20073/ATGInstallGuide/html/s0902tomcatconnectorthreadconfigurati01.html) for example. They help handle several requests through threading.

Comment: @AlexanderTorstling you're completely wrong. A servlet is a singleton, and is shared among all the requests. Each request is served by a thread, and concurrent requests are thus served by concurrent threads, each calling the same servlet concurrently.

Comment: For the record, paragraph 2.2 of the servlet 3.0 specifications: "For a servlet not hosted in a distributed environment (the default), the servlet container must use only one instance per servlet declaration."

Comment: in one Application context only one instance of servlet is instantiated. threads are allocated by container for every new request. you can check more details in Book

Comment: @Prashant that is also wrong. Creating a new thread for each request would be a waste of resources. The container typically uses a pool of threads, and threads are thus reused to serve multiple requests (but one at a time for each thread).

Comment: @JBNizet : i meant that only.. :) i will change my comment!!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Struts/Spring frameworks are actually written on top of Servlet specification so doesn't matter what you use underneath it use Servlets.

You are right, Only single instance of Servlet is created, but that instance is shared across multiple threads. For this reason you should never have shared mutable states in your Servlets.

For example you have following servlet mapped to `http://localhost/myservlet`

```
class MySerlvet extends HttpServlet {

     public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
          // Get Logic
     }    
}
```

The Web Server will have something similar (Not necessarily same) in its code.

```
MyServlet m = new MyServlet(); // This will be created once

// for each request for http://localhost/myservlet
executorService.submit(new RequestProcessingThread(m));
```

Comment: does this mean, all threads in some form call m.service() as per your example

Comment: @Bharat yes. all threads will call m.service() / m.doGet()

Comment: @shazin Does the `executorService.submit(new RequestProcessingThread(m))` part for each request have its own dedicated socket, similar to one returned by `ServerSocket.accept()` call in a typical multithreaded, socket server code?

Comment: @Harry In tomcat it has a TCP connection per request which is controlled by maxConnections argument.

Comment: @shazin Thanks. Is this documented in the official documentation, or elsewhere? Or, do you know this from having studied the Tomcat code itself?

Answer (score 45):

Each request is processed in a separated thread. This doesn't mean Tomcat creates a new thread per request. There is a pool of threads to process requests. Also there is a single instance for each servlet and this is the default case.([Some more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509830/does-each-request-access-the-same-servlet-object)).
Your servlet should be `Thread Safe` i.e. it should be stateless.

[image]

If your servlet implements `SingleThreadModel` interface, each thread uses separate instance of servlet. [`SingleThreadModel` is deprecated](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/SingleThreadModel.html), Don't use it.

[image: SingleThreadModel]

I made this answer as community wiki.

Comment: So in this case , what is the mechanism behind this scenario?. If we don't use the SingleThreadModel , the servlet is not thread safe , how can we overcome this problem?

Comment: @xtiger: There is many ways to make your servlet as Thread-safe. For example if you don't use variables which are defined in class scope it will be Thread-safe.

Comment: @Ali Sepehri.Kh what did you mean by "I made this answer as community wiki." ?

Answer (score 8):

You don't create multiple instances of servlet. The servlet engine utilizes a separate thread from the thread pool for each request (up to some max number of Threads allocated).

The performance is relative to the number of threads, not the number of instances of the servlet.

For example, if there are 1000 requests, and the maximum threads that can be generated by servlet is 100, then there will be performance degradation.

In order to avoid this problem, we can use **load balancer** by putting multiple servers behind a load balancer.
The load balancer should be configured to "route" the requests to any one of the servers based upon different parameters/settings (round robin distribution, load distribution etc.). The more load you need, the more servers you should add. However, this does send all traffic through the load balancer so it is important that this be redundant and failover safe.