# if multiple requests are handled by a server to run a single servlet then where we need to take care of synchronization?

Tags: java, multithreading

If multiple requests are handled by a server to run a single servlet then where we need to take care of synchronization?

I have got the answer from [How does a single servlet handle multiple requests from client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27765547/how-does-a-single-servlet-handle-multiple-requests-from-client-side) how multiple requests are handled. But then again there is a question that why we need synchronization  if all requests are handled separately?

Can you give some real life example how a shared state works and how a servlet can be dependent? I am not much interested in code but looking for explanation with example of any portal application? Like if there is any login page how it is accessed by n number of users concurrently.

If more than one request is handled by the server.. like what I read is server make a thread pool of n threads to serve the requests and I guess each thread will have their own set of parameters to maintain the session... so is there any chance that two or more threads (means two or more requests) can collide with each other?

Answer (score 0):

Synchronization is required when multiple threads are **modifying** a **shared** resources.

So, when all your servlets are independent of each other, you don't worry about the fact that they run in parallel.

But, if they work on "shared state" somehow (for example by reading/writing values into some sort of centralized data store); then you have to make sure that things don't go wrong. Of course: the layer/form how to provide the necessary synchronization to your application depends on your exact setup.

Yes, my answer is pretty generic; but so is your question.

Comment: ok so, let's say you access a URL :   something/abc... this URL interacts with DB and get the data updated? now it is hit by 1000 users? then it should be made threadsafe ?

Comment: It doesn't matter if there are 1000 users or just two. The key question is: what should happen when requests come in **in parallel**. I **assume** you dont want your data to be corrupted; so you have to take appropriate counter measures. How those look like; I can't tell: it is **your** application.

Comment: can you give real life example how a shared state works and how a servlet can be dependent?  i am not much interested in code but looking for explanation with example of any portal application? like if there is any login page how it is accessed by n number of users concurrently ?

Comment: my question was... if more than one request is handled by the server.. like what i read is server make a thread pool of n threads to serve the requests and i guess each thread will have their own set of parameters to maintain the session... so is there any chance that two or more threads (means two or more requests) can collide with each other?

Comment: Please dont push such information into comments. Update your question instead! Avoid getting into this kind of comment-discussions thing!

Answer (score 0):

Synchronization in Java will only be needed if shared object is mutable. if your shared object is either read-only or immutable object, then you don't need synchronization, despite running multiple threads. Same is true with what threads are doing with an object if all the threads are only reading value then you don't require synchronization in Java.

[Read more](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/04/synchronization-in-java-synchronized.html#ixzz4K1VAGY2o)

Comment: i Understand why it requires http://www.diaryreaders.com/why-synchronization/  ... but question wants the above why synchronization. i am looking for scenarios in real worlds application ???

Answer (score 0):

Basically if your servlet application is multi-threaded, then data associated with servlet will not be thread safe. The common example given in many text books are things like a hit counter, stored as a private variable:

e.g

```
public class YourServlet implements Servlet {

    private int counter;

    public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse, res) {

        //this is not thread safe
        counter ++;

    }

}
```

This is because the service method and Servlet is operated on by multiple thread incoming as HTTP requests. The unary increment operator has to firstly read the current value, add one and the write the value back. Another thread doing the same operation concurrently, may increment the value after the first thread has read the value, but before it is written back, thus resulting in a lost write.

So in this case you should use synchronisation, or even better, the AtomicInteger class included as part of Java Concurrency from 1.5 onwards.

Comment: so you are saying, if multiple request are coming to the server and server instantiates multiple threads, then if these multiple threads access the same method for reading and writing then that methods should apply thread safe?

Comment: If they operate on the same shared object, i.e the Servlet, then yes, the methods that operate on the data encapsulated by the object need to be thread safe.

Comment: i was trying to know  how "object" is called as shared object? if multiple request are coming to the server and server instantiates multiple threads, then if these multiple threads access the same method for reading and writing ? then can i call this object of this servlet as shared object? and should i go thread safety of that method?

Comment: please give some real examples. examples with complete flow.. like more than 2 request hits the portal?  what will happen ? they hit the same resource..? what will happen? does this resource should be thread safe?

Comment: the discussion you have cited http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27765547/how-does-a-single-servlet-handle-multiple-requests-from-client-side already has some pretty good examples of how threads are created by an application server.