# Can we declare a field outside the method in servlet

Tags: java, servlets

can we declare a object of a class as an instance variable in a servlet

```
public class BookServ extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // declared object
    User user=new User();

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
         ...
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: no problem but is it correct to declare like this or is there any other way

Comment: are you talking for some coding architecture...

Comment: yeah.... Lokesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can.

A `User` field makes not much sense, since your container would normally instantiate exactly ONE servlet instance with exactly ONE contained `User` instance. 
But this Servlet instance is allowed to run multiply in parallel on several threads, so several threads may access the single `User` instance concurrently.

You might want to store state within the servlet, which are initialized in the `init()` method of the servlet:

```
    public class BookServ extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private String servletUID = null;

        public void init() throws ServletException {
            servletUID = ... generate a random String as UID ...
        }

        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {    
              ...
        }
    }
```

Nevertheless you should be aware that there are several contexts, which should be used to store servlet data (`request.getServletContext()`), session data (`request.getSession()` or request data (`request.setAttribute()`/`request.getAttribute()`) to.
So normally there is little need for fields within servlets.

Also check 
[How do servlets work? Instantiation, sessions, shared variables and multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-sessions-shared-variables-and-multithreadi?rq=1)

Comment: the User is a normal java class ,here i should get data from that User class through the servlet bookServ ,myquestion is can i use the same object user for all doget,dopost and dodelete methods or should i declare the object in all the methods.

Comment: Only one Servlet instance is created.
Therefore it is highly NOT recommended to save data in servlet fields. I guess for the `User` instance the best place to save it is `SessionContext`.

Comment: @Dmitriy Popov: you're definitly right: don't save data in servlet fields, but regarding the "one Servlet instance" it depends: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509830/does-each-request-access-the-same-servlet-object